# Discrete distribution coefficient calculation

Tags: cumulative-distribution-functions

Given distribution function $F(x)$:

[image]

Determine the interval boundary coefficient $c$, the density function and the mathematical expectation.

In my opinion, to get $c$ you have to differentiate $F(x)$ by that getting $f(x)$.
Then we would get an integrated $(4x)$ within (from $0$ to $c$) which should be equal to $1$.

As a result $4c = 1\Rightarrow c=1/4$. Can someone confirm if I am correct?

Comment: Is $1+1$ in the image a typo?

Comment: Title is strange. This is certainly not  a discrete distribution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @geetha290krm (1+1) was in task, so, can write 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F$ satisfes all the properties of a  CDF as long as $c>0, 2c^{2}\le 1$, so we need $0<c\leq \frac 1 {\sqrt 2 }$.

This CDF need not have a density. It can have jump at $c$. If you assume that there is no jump at $c$ then  we need $2c^{2}=1$ or $c=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$.

The density function  in this  case is $f(x)=4x, 0<x<c$ and the mean is $\int_0^{c}4x^{2}dx=\frac  4 3 c^{3}=\frac 2 {3 \sqrt 2}$.